# What ways are there to edit corrections for Gboard for iOS?

Tags: ios, keyboard

I'm using Gboard for iOS. Often when I enter a word using the swiping technique it comes up with the wrong word and no suggestion for the word I actually want. The word I want is often only 1 or 2 characters different so my instinct is to press backspace to correct the word but backspace deletes the entire word forcing me to re-enter the entire word again. Usually I end up doing this twice before I realize I have to enter the word by tapping instead of swiping to get what I want.

Are there other methods of correcting/editing a word using Gboard?

Answer (score 1):

You can move the cursor by sliding your finger on the spacebar. Using this technique I can move the cursor back and fix a letter although fixing the last letter is a little problematic. AFAICT to edit the last letter move cursor left then right and pressing backspace won't delete the entire word just the last letter.